# Can I use the T-mobile contract free iPhone 5S with my AT&T number?

Tags: unlock, sim, iphone

I am thinking of purchasing the contract-free 5S because my contract with AT&T just expired, and I will only need the phone in the US for a few more months.  Will I be able to use my AT&T sim card (I currently have a 4S) when I receive the T-mobile contract free 5S? Also, I assume I will be able to take it abroad with me and use an international carrier once I move abroad at the end of the year.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score -1):

Yes, as long as you buy it from Apple's online store.

Comment: This is demonstrably false. Apple sells the same product in its retail stores as it's online stores, so perhaps there is more you could add to explain your reasoning?